# Replacing part of std::vector by smaller std::vector

Tags: c++11, vector, replace, stdvector

I wonder what would be the correct way to replace (overwriting) a part of a given std::vector "input" by another, smaller std::vector?
I do neet to keep the rest of the original vector unchanged.
Also I do not need to bother what has been in the original vector and
I don't need to keep the smaller vector afterwards anymore.

Say I have this:

```
std::vector<int> input = { 0, 0, 1, 1, 2, 22, 3, 33, 99 };
std::vector<int> a = { 1, 2, 3 };
std::vector<int> b = { 4, 5, 6, 7, 8 };
```

And I want to achieve that:

```
input = { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 99}
```

What is the right way to do it? I thought of something like

```
input.replace(input.beginn(), input.beginn()+a.size(), a);
// intermediate input would look like that: input = { 1, 2, 3, 1, 2, 22, 3, 33, 99 };

input.replace(input.beginn()+a.size(), input.beginn()+a.size()+b.size(), b);
```

There should be a standard way to do it, shouldn't it?
My thoughts on this so far are the following:

- I can not use std::vector::assign for it destroys all elements of input
- std::vector::push_back would not replace but enlarge the input --> not what I want
- std::vector::insert also creates new elements and enlages the input vector but I know for sure that the vectors a.size() + b.size() <= input.size()
- std::vector::swap would not work since there is some content of input that needs to remain there ( in the example the last element) also it would not work to add b that way
- std::vector::emplace also increases the input.size -> seems wrong as well

Also I would prefer if the solution would not waste performance by unnecessary clears or writing back values into the vectors a or b. My vectors will be very large for real and this is about performance in the end.

Any competent help would be appreciated very much.

Comment: Are you looking for [`std::copy`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/copy)? If I understand your question correctly (not sure) then [this](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/755867ac783ad0a7) should be what you want. If it is, let me know and I'll post it as an answer.

Comment: It seems to be what I am after though I do not quite understand it entirely.
With OutputIt copy( InputIt first, InputIt last, OutputIt d_first );
would it be: first = a.beginn(), last = a.end() d_first = input.beginn()

also I can not understand the meaning of 
"For std::copy function d_first shall not be in the range [first, last). std::copy_backward must be used in that case. "

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You seem to be after [`std::copy()`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/copy). This is how you would use it in your example ([live demo on Coliru](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/755867ac783ad0a7)):

```
#include <algorithm> // Necessary for `std::copy`...

// ...

std::vector<int> input = { 0, 0, 1, 1, 2, 22, 3, 33, 99 };
std::vector<int> a = { 1, 2, 3 };
std::vector<int> b = { 4, 5, 6, 7, 8 };    

std::copy(std::begin(a), std::end(a), std::begin(input));
std::copy(std::begin(b), std::end(b), std::begin(input) + a.size());
```

As Zyx2000 notes [in the comments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28013793/replacing-part-of-stdvector-by-smaller-stdvector/28014123#comment44418364_28014123), in this case you can also use the iterator returned by the first call to `std::copy()` as the insertion point for the next copy:

```
auto last = std::copy(std::begin(a), std::end(a), std::begin(input));
std::copy(std::begin(b), std::end(b), last);
```

This way, random-access iterators are no longer required - that was the case when we had the expression `std::begin(input) + a.size()`.

The first two arguments to `std::copy()` denote the source range of elements you want to copy. The third argument is an iterator to the first element you want to overwrite in the destination container.

When using `std::copy()`, make sure that the destination container is large enough to accommodate the number of elements you intend to copy.

Also, the source and the target range should not interleave.

Comment: The code can be made more general, by replacing `std::begin(input) + a.size()` with the return value of the first call to `std::copy`. Then it works even when the iterators aren't random access iterators ([Example](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/25c25acf94ad0807)).

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <algorithm>

int main() {
    std::vector<int> input = { 0, 0, 1, 1, 2, 22, 3, 33, 99 };
    std::vector<int> a = { 1, 2, 3 };
    std::vector<int> b = { 4, 5, 6, 7, 8 };

    std::set_union( a.begin(), a.end(), b.begin(), b.end(), input.begin() );

    for ( std::vector<int>::const_iterator iter = input.begin();
          iter != input.end();
          ++iter )
    {
        std::cout << *iter << " ";
    }

    return 0;
}
```

It outputs:

```
1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 99
```

Comment: I am not 100% sure yet but this does not seems to be the right answer. I can not guarantee that a and b are allways orderd nor that the input elements that need to stay are larger than all prior ones.

Also I would like to keep the writing and memmoryallocation minimal, for i might use vectors of very , very large size. Reusing the input would save me from additional memory allocation since the output will have the exact same size as the input which is no longer needed by then.